# Can I work as a "corporation" in EU for the sole proprietorship I have in USA?

Tags: usa, taxes, eu, company

I have been working as a (as a sole proprietor, contract-based) IT consultant here in USA for some years.

Now I have been thinking about accepting a role in UK. I am an EU citizen but since the role is not necessarily very long (maybe 6 months+) I will still have a mailing address here in USA.

I know the differences between S-Corps and sole proprietorships but I was not sure if I can be classified as a sole proprietor when working outside of the country. Does work that is outside of the country require e.g. an S-Corp (other other form of registered corporation), or can I do it as a sole proprietor?

Comment: Are you asking about US taxes? S-Corp is a US-specific term.

Comment: In the UK the normal term for working for yourself is [Self Employed](https://www.gov.uk/business-tax/self-employed) - is that the kind of setup you currently have?

Comment: Putting on hold until questions are clarified as per the comments above.